# How do I get at line/column of the XML file using perl's XML::SAX

Tags: xml, perl, sax

When I parse XML and find a problem, I would like to tell where the problem is, i.e. at least print a line number. Here's a complete little example:

```
use XML::SAX;
my $gFactory = XML::SAX::ParserFactory->new ();
my $gParser = $gFactory->parser (Handler => EventHandler->new ());
$gParser->parse_uri ("foo.xml");
exit 0;

package EventHandler;
use base 'XML::SAX::Base';

sub start_element {
  my ($aSelf, $aElement) = @_;
  my ($name, $attributes) = ($aElement->{Name}, $aElement->{Attributes});
  print "at line/column/byte ...\n";
}
```

What would I use in the print statement?
I've searched the 'net and found XML::SAX::DocumentLocator but am unsure if that's what I'm looking for and if so, how to use it. Any gentle prodding in the right direction deeply appreciated!

PS: It appears the parser used under the hood is libxml.

JJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I switched to using `XML::Parser::PerlSax`. This module has a method `location()` to return a hash with file, line, colum position that does the trick.
See https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Parser::PerlSAX

Answer (score 1):

From this page (http://perl-xml.sourceforge.net/perl-sax/sax-2.1-ref.html), it seems straight-forward..
Under Exceptions it says:

> If the exception is raised due to
>   parse errors, these properties are
>   also available:
>
> ```
> ColumnNumber  The column number of the end of the text where the
> ```
>
> exception occurred.
>       LineNumber    The line number of the end of the text where the exception
>   occurred.
>       PublicId  The public identifier of the entity where the exception
>   occurred.
>       SystemId  The system identifier of the entity where the exception
>   occurred.

Looks like you can get a line number and column number if a parsing exception or validation error occurs.
As it says on the page I mentioned: "Conformant XML parsers are required to abort processing when well-formedness or validation errors occur."

Validation would include attribute names, wouldn't it?

Comment: Thanks Spaceghost, but well-formedness errors are already diagnosed by the parser with location info. I should have been more precise: I would like to point out, for example, invalid attribute names, invalid values, in other words, errors in the semantics of the data, not the syntax. JJ

Comment: I paraphrased the page.. they also include validation errors as a source of exceptions.

Comment: Validation can only do very limited checking, I need to do much more. Think of a numeric attribute value that must be a prime. I'd like to `print "Line 200: attribute n='42' is not a prime"`. I'm sure the parser state contains line/column/offset somewhere when start_element is callled. But how do I access it?

Comment: Ok, you want to find the problem and then report it? Then you need to throw an error when you find, for example, a non-prime numeric attribute value which will be caught by the exception hadnling mechanism and, presto, you get a line number.

Comment: Hmm. Calling `$aSelf->error("foo")` is a no-op; it's another method like start_element, which, if not implemented by the EventHandler package, has a dummy no-op implementation. With an expat parser it would be as easy as referencing $aSelf->current_line. There's nothing similar for SAX with libxml? How would you throw the exception you suggested? Thanks four your patience with me :-)